# Why datetime variable php show yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss instead in html input show only yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, html

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM lista_utenti, tbl_users, prodotti 
                      WHERE lista_utenti.userID= tbl_users.userID 
                        AND prodotti.id_prod= lista_utenti.id_prod 
                        AND tbl_users.codice= '$codice' 
                        AND lista_utenti.stato='0'"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data=$row['data'];
    echo '<tr class="clickable warning dropdown-deliverable" >';
    echo "<td >".$row['data']."</td>"; //this show yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss
}
echo '<td>
         <form action="approva.php" method="get">
         <input type="hidden" name="data1" value='.$data.' /> 
         <input type="text" name="data1" value='.$data.' /> //this show ONLY yyyy-mm-dd 
         <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="btn-approva" id="btn-approva"> Approva </button>
         </form>
      </td>';
```

Comment: change input type from text to datetime

Comment: @clearshot66 Why would text not show the whole thing?

Comment: @Barmar it should if done correctly but easiest for him to have it the way he wants would be to put datetime as type

Comment: `type=datetime` isn't supported by most browsers.

Comment: most is incorrect. HTML 5 browsers support it.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: What is the DataType of the `data` column? I am guessing its not DATETIME!

Comment: It's because you're not containing the value. Use "" around the `'. $data.'` so it becomes `"'.$data.'"`

Comment: junkfoodjunkie it works! Thank you so much! Thanks also to all of you to answer me